# Cygwin to use my windows username in path?

Tags: windows, authentication, cygwin

I'm writing a script where Cygwin needs to cp a file from my desktop.

```
cp /cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/Desktop/file /tmp/file
```

How can I make Cygwin get my  or the username of the person who is currently running it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in a different answer,
The profile of the current user is $USERPROFILE.

Putting them together it becomes:

```
cp $USERPROFILE/Desktop/file /tmp/file
```

Comment: try `realCurrentUser=$(mkpasswd -c|sed 's/:.*$//')` .